# SELECT after INSERT with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, select

I am making a comment system and I have it just about setup, other than one thing. Right now I `INSERT` the comment with AJAX/PHP and select it on the comment page during page load. The item I cannot figure out is how to `SELECT` the comments after I `INSERT` them to enable the message to appear without page loading.

I have the select query already made up (on the comments page), can I just add that to the php file and have php send back the data or what do I do?

I am including all of my code to show the system I have now. Ideally I would like to keep everything within these files and efficiently use any code I have.

How can I do this?

Form and `SELECT` query on the comments page:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="comment-form">
            <label for="comment">Comment</label>
            <textarea cols="15" id="home_comment" name="comment" placeholder="Message" rows="5" maxlength="1000" required></textarea><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
            <input id="comment-button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Post">
        </form>
<?php
$select_comments_sql = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM home_comments
    ORDER BY id DESC
";
  if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
        //$select_comments_stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
        $select_comments_stmt->execute();
        if (!$select_comments_stmt->errno) {
            //echo "error";
        }
        $select_comments_stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $comment_user_id, $comment_username, $home_comments, $comment_date);

        $comment_array = array();
        while ($select_comments_stmt->fetch()) {
            $comment_array[] = $comment_user_id;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_username;
            $comment_array[] = $home_comments;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_date;
            if ($home_comments === NULL) {
                echo 'No comments found.';
            } else {
                echo $comment_username. "<br>";
                echo $home_comments. "<br><br><br>";
            }
        }   
  }
```

AJAX for `INSERT`

```
$("#comment-form").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var home_comment = $("#home_comment").val();

        $.ajax({ 
            url: "ajax-php/comment-send.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "home_comment": home_comment
            },
            success: function (data) {
            //  console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
                if (data == "Error!") {
                    alert("Unable to post comment!");
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    $("#comment-form")[0].reset();
                    //$('.newsletter-popup').fadeIn(350).delay(2000).fadeOut();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
                console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
            }
        });
    });
```

PHP file for `INSERT`

```
$user = new User();

$home_comment = $_POST['home_comment'];
$username = $user->data()->username;
$okay = true;

if ( $okay ) { 

    $comment_insert = "
        INSERT INTO home_comments 
        (id, user_id, username, comment, date)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())
        ";
    $comment_stmt = $con->prepare($comment_insert);
    $comment_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $id, $user_id, $username, $home_comment);
    $comment_stmt->execute();
    }
```

Comment: All you need to know is if the row is successfully inserted. So if your insert script can confirm that, you don't need to select anything as you already have the comment available in javascript, the `home_comment` variable. So just add that to the comments that are already there.

Comment: Well I am only sending the comment data over, but I will also need to know the username, date, etc to display on the page, but how do I add it to what's already there?

Comment: I assumed you already had that available as well... Adding a new comment is easy with jQuery using for example `.append()`.

Comment: I just don't understand how to make that work with this.

Answer (score 1):

Please try as bellow

```
<ul id="CommentsList">
        <?php
    $select_comments_sql = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM home_comments
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ";
      if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
            //$select_comments_stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
            $select_comments_stmt->execute();
            if (!$select_comments_stmt->errno) {
                //echo "error";
            }
            $select_comments_stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $comment_user_id, $comment_username, $home_comments, $comment_date);

            $comment_array = array();
            while ($select_comments_stmt->fetch()) {
                $comment_array[] = $comment_user_id;
                $comment_array[] = $comment_username;
                $comment_array[] = $home_comments;
                $comment_array[] = $comment_date;


                echo '<li>';
                    if ($home_comments === NULL) {
                        echo '<p>No comments found.</p>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<p>'.$comment_username.'</p>';
                        echo '<p>'.$home_comments.'<p>';
                    }
                echo '</li>';
            }  }  ?>  </ul>
```

In Ajax :

Please add bellow code fro success

```
success: function (data) {
           $('#CommentsList').prepend(data);
    },
```

PHP file for INSERT :

Please add bellow code( Please correct if any misstates to retrieve data) after insert ($comment_stmt->execute();)

```
//Get the last insert id
    if($last_id = $comment_stmt->lastInsertId()){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM home_comments where id=".$last_id;
        if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {
            $select_comments_stmt->execute();
             $select_comments_stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $comment_user_id, $comment_username, $home_comments, $comment_date);
             while ($select_comments_stmt->fetch()) {
              $comment_array[] = $comment_user_id;
                $comment_array[] = $comment_username;
                $comment_array[] = $home_comments;
                $comment_array[] = $comment_date;       
                echo '<li>';
                if ($home_comments === NULL) {
                    echo '<p>No comments found.</p>';
                } else {
                    echo '<p>'.$comment_username.'</p>';
                    echo '<p>'.$home_comments.'<p>';
                }
                echo '</li>';
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have created jsfiddle example for prepend. please check this once https://jsfiddle.net/35x5r12w/

Comment: But how do I get the data back from php to prepend it?

Comment: Whatever you wrote in the php file(comment-send.php) that is going to saved as data parameter of success function ..so i have prepended that data to "div"($('#CommentsList').prepend(data);)

Answer (score 0):

In your comment form page : remove `select` query system. You just add a `div` like `<div class="comment-result"></div>`. If Ajax request is success then `append` data in `comment-result` `div`

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="comment-form">
    <label for="comment">Comment</label>
    <textarea cols="15" id="home_comment" name="comment" placeholder="Message" rows="5" maxlength="1000" required></textarea><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    <input id="comment-button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Post">
</form>

<div class="comment-result">

</div>
```

PHP file for INSERT and SELECT. I have added `Select` query after `insert` comment.

```
<?php
$user = new User();

$home_comment = $_POST['home_comment'];
$username = $user->data()->username;
$okay = true;

if ( $okay ) { 
    $comment_insert = "
    INSERT INTO home_comments 
    (id, user_id, username, comment, date)
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())
    ";
    $comment_stmt = $con->prepare($comment_insert);
    $comment_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $id, $user_id, $username, $home_comment);
    $comment_stmt->execute();

    //select all comment list
    $select_comments_sql = "SELECT *FROM home_comments ORDER BY id DESC";

    if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
        //$select_comments_stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
        $select_comments_stmt->execute();
        if (!$select_comments_stmt->errno) {
            //echo "error";
        }
        $select_comments_stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $comment_user_id, $comment_username, $home_comments, $comment_date);

        $comment_array = array();
        while ($select_comments_stmt->fetch()) {
            $comment_array[] = $comment_user_id;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_username;
            $comment_array[] = $home_comments;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_date;
            if ($home_comments === NULL) {
                echo 'No comments found.';
            } else {
                echo $comment_username. "<br>";
                echo $home_comments. "<br><br><br>";
            }
        }   
    }
}
?>
```

AJAX for INSERT and SELECT (I have added new line `$('.comment-result').prepend(data);`)

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data == "Error!") {
        alert("Unable to post comment!");
        alert(data);
    } else {
        $("#comment-form")[0].reset();
        $('.comment-result').append(data); //added new line
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't removing the select query from my comment file not allow the results to show unless someone commented?